# Is there a solution to connect volunteermatch.org with Salesforce?

Tags: integration, connected-apps, npsp

I want to know if there is a solution to integrate or even connect the volunteermatch.org platform with the Salesforce?
any ideas?

Comment: when you talk about 'to connect', are you talking about integration, displaying pages that will lead users to salesforce data?

Comment: integration is ideal but connection is also acceptable

Comment: As I see it, volunteermatch.org is a website. Do you want to capture data from that site and send it to SFDC? Do you want to share data from SFDC to your visitors? What is exactly what you intend to do? Are you talking about surveys, forms? Please, elaborate a bit more on what you are really looking for in order for us to help you.

Comment: I want to create a workflow that capture the 3 main types of people I need tracked , one of these types is Volunteer Management(Sourcing, qualifying, onboarding, assigning work, tracking hours, and closing out)
 We use 3 primary systems for this. Volunteermatch.com and Podio/SharePoint for work assignment.
So I need a solution to capture all the information from this platform into SFDC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you can do in order to integrate your platforms with SFDC.
For **Podio** you can use an extension like [this](https://podio.com/extensions/33) one. 
There are other options like [this](https://zapier.com/zapbook/podio/salesforce/) one. So it would be good for you to do a search on these and other extensions.

For your **Share Point** I think that probably you need Microsoft Azure. There are several examples on how to use Microsoft Azure and Salesforce to get integrated.

For your **website** or even other integrations, you can use the [Developer API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm)

You can use Leads or Cases if that is what you need in a very easy way, check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2VNmg4F4ho) video.

To resume, there are options that will allow you to integrate your systems that are part of your IT architecture but you need to investigate what will be the best possible solution.

Comment: Carlos I appreciate for your generous reply.
I definitely follow all the solutions you shared. They are very helpful 
kindly regards